# Eigen Library : Different behaviors between static and dynamic size matrices when computing inverse

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3, matrix-inverse

I experienced some strange behavior from Eigen library when computing inverse of small `float` matrices . I found unexpected differences between using the same data for static and dynamic matrix sizes.

Even more surprising, when comparing to what I would get using `double` matrices, it seems that only the dynamic version provides a satisfying result.

So what am I missing here ? Does it mean I should use the dynamic version in all cases ? It just cant be right.

Here is a code sample, compiled with Visual Studio 2012, Release, x64.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    //some static size 4x3 matrix
    Eigen::Matrix<float,4,3> m;
    m <<
        -166.863f,  -172.49f,   -172.49f,
        107.422f,   101.71f,    107.422f,
        708.306f,   706.599f,   708.029f,
        1.0f,       1.0f,       1.0f ;

    //same but dynamic size
    Eigen::MatrixXf mx = m;

    //first result
    std::cout << (m.transpose()*m).inverse()  << std::endl << std::endl ;
    /*
        0.00490293 0.000445721 -0.00533875
        0.000445721  0.00502179  -0.0054378
        -0.00533875  -0.0054378   0.0107567
    */

    //second result, completely different from the first one
    std::cout << (mx.transpose()*mx).inverse() << std::endl << std::endl ;
    /*
        0.0328157 0.00291519 -0.0356753
        0.00287851  0.0337197  -0.036493
        -0.0356387 -0.0365297  0.0720099
    */

    //third result, same as the second one, only small differences due to better accuracy
    std::cout << (m.transpose()*m).cast<double>().inverse() << std::endl << std::endl ;
    /*
        0.032961 0.00297425 -0.0358793
        0.00297425  0.0337394 -0.0366082
        -0.0358793 -0.0366082  0.0723284
    */

    //the condition number of the inversed matrix is quite huge if that matters : 175918
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf> svdF(m.transpose()*m);
    std::cout << svdF.singularValues()(0) / svdF.singularValues()(svdF.singularValues().size()-1) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented by Eigen, the [inverse](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a9341199ed1cd9c0e1019907de75bd502) uses a different algorithm for small fixed matrices (up to 4x4).

For small fixed matrices, Eigen uses the [cofactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) method (Cramers's rule). This method is based on the calculation of determinants, which is calculated by subtracting products. For high condition numbers and/or low floating point precision, you obtain high relative errors.

For other matrices, Eigen uses a Partial Pivoting LU decomposition, which is more stable than the cofactors method.

Comment: I was expecting something like this, but I fail to understand why Eigen is using a non-stable algorithm when the matrix size is known. Having more information about the matrix should only improves things. Or maybe it is just a speed/quality trade off ?

Comment: It is indeed a trade off between speed and quality. Eigen has [much more methods](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) to calculate the inverse, each with its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I see. I guess that's why [openGL matrix inverse](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/inverse.xhtml), which focus on speed, is undefined for both non-invertible and poorly conditioned matrices.